# Calculated field with library folder name

Tags: calculated-column, folder, calculated-column-formula, display-name, email-enabled-library

I have a library (e-amil enabled) with e-mail with attachments and I need to make a calulated field using the e-mail subject. The problem is that the calculated field shows only when I drill down the folder it creates with attachments and .eml file. How to show the field in folder level too? The calculated field is "Test" and i need to have "test 1" in the folder level where I have "0" now.
[image: I need to show the field here, i see just 0]

[image: When drill down the field works]

Comment: This is not particulary clear: is this an email enabled document library?

Comment: yes it is, I need to show the e-mail subject in the folder level, it's the same as the the column "Name" in the first image. Calculated field "test" is now just =e-mail subject, but i will concatenate it with others.